# Postgis error on select all intersetcs of a polygon

Tags: gis, polygon, postgis, intersection

i can get all polygon on intersects this:-7.9245860488441 -37.122384500713,-7.9245860488441 -37.11904223938,-7.9233955716106 -37.1187601948

```
SELECT * 
FROM propriedades 
WHERE ST_Intersects(
    ST_GeomFromText(location::geometry),
    ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON(-7.9245860488441 -37.122384500713,-7.9245860488441 -37.11904223938,-7.9233955716106 -37.1187601948)'));
```

propriedades is my table
location is a colunm on are saved geography polygons

the returned error

> ERROR:  parse error - invalid geometry HINT: 
>   "POLYGON(-7.9245860488441 " <-- parse error at position 25 within
>   geometry
>
> *** *Error* *****
>
> ERROR: parse error - invalid geometry SQL state: XX000 Hint:
>   "POLYGON(-7.9245860488441 " <-- parse error at position 25 within
>   geometry

solved, i used the geography, no geometry:

```
SELECT * 
FROM propriedades 
WHERE ST_Intersects(
    location,
    'POLYGON((-7.9239281216632 -37.118491021708,-7.9239281216632 -37.116096663161,-7.9240937813677 -37.116105295265,-7.9241591799314 -37.116171875421,-7.9246636046819 -37.116271405188,-7.9259677455811 -37.118572530098,-7.9256079206171 -37.118728486796,-7.9243335012771 -37.118675962065,-7.9243194973485 -37.11849254918,-7.9242705964918 -37.118491021708,-7.9239281216632 -37.118491021708))'
)
```

but i have other problem, i want intersects > 50 meters

like this http://slimber.com/gallery/pictures2/23/235563/polygons.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with the WKT of the polygon, which is why it cannot be parsed. Polygons need two depths of parentheses, and the last coordinate needs to match the first coordinate to make a closed linear ring (i.e., [triangles require four points](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10308/why-do-valid-polygons-repeat-the-same-start-and-end-point)). The WKT should look like this:

```
POLYGON((-7.9245860488441 -37.122384500713, -7.9245860488441 -37.11904223938,
         -7.9233955716106 -37.1187601948, -7.9245860488441 -37.122384500713))
```

Also `ST_GeomFromText(location::geometry)` is really unnecessary, since `::geometry` is already a PostgreSQL cast operator to `geometry`. If it is a `geography` type, then `location::geometry` should be sufficient to cast it as `geometry`.